# How to specify RTL drawable folder names for Night mode in android

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, android-night-mode

> drawable-ldrtl-hdpi

is the folder name for RTL support then what should it be named for Night Mode?

> drawable-night-ldrtl-hdpi

As this gives Error: Invalid resource directory name

Answer (score 0):

This should be like this

> drawable-ldrtl-night-hdpi